# Foursquare Get All Unique Checkins Once Time (Checkins/VenueHistory)

Tags: foursquare

I need to get user's all unique checkins data.

For example, I have 12000 checkins, which 4500 checkins are unique, 7500 are multiple.

There are 2 ways to get user checkins.

1. users/self/checkins
2. users/self/venuehistory

When I used **1st** method, I get max 250 items once time. I have to use a loop, but it is increasing my request count. I will make 48 (12000/250) request for get 12000 checkins, also I get 7500 checkins for nothing, because these are multiple checkins. I need just 4500 unique checkins.

When I use **2nd** method, I get max unique 3000 items once time. But there are no offset, skip or paging at this method. I cant get 1500 items like this.

Is there any solution to do this once time or less request count?